# Need run that macro on multiple files

Tags: vba, excel

This macro is supposed to go through all folders/sub-folders, find all Excel files and remove white-spaces from a specific cell.
The problem is that when I run it, it asks to reopen the current XLS document, and if I accept, it reopen but then the macro stops and disappears.
What is wrong in the code? I guess I shouldn't be opening files like that, is there anyway to update cell values without opening them or opening them differently?
Code:

```
Sub Main()
    Call RecursiveFolders("C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Folder")
End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolders(ByVal MyPath As String)
    Dim FileSys As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim wkbOpen As Workbook
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook

    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(MyPath)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        For Each objFile In objSubFolder.Files
            Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=objFile)
            '//For each file do that
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Dim tmp

            For Each ws In Worksheets
                ws.Range("E6") = Replace(ws.Range("E6"), " ", "", 1, -1)
            Next
            wkbOpen.Close savechanges:=True
        Next

        Call RecursiveFolders(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: try to change `For Each ws In Worksheets` to `For Each ws In wkbOpen.Worksheets`

Comment: It asks to reopen my current file, I click yes then it stop running I guess.

Comment: I guess I'll try C#, maybe VBA doesn't handle editing multiple files well, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: if you open up the file with the macro, it needs to close it (exit the macro)... make sure it doesnt open the WB with the macro (or a WB with the same name)

Comment: Ok I'm going to test in a file that is not in these folders

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If you want to add an answer, feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want the points XD

> if you open up the file with the macro, it needs to close it (exit the macro)... make sure it doesn't open the WB with the macro (or a WB with the same name)<